# How to store Flash-based games data into server

Tags: javascript, flash, web, blogger, data-storage

I have [this website](http://physicsgames.tk), I'll be happy if I could store the game progress of the user, and then retrieve it to their respective users when they login. Is there any way to do this? Maybe storing the data to a DB. I was reading on Internet and I found something about *Shared Objects*. I don't know if it is useful, I hope it will.. Thanks in advance and sorry for my English.

EDIT: I publish external games, I didn't develop them.

Comment: you can use PHP and Mysql to store your data into server. The games are build with which version of actionscript? AS2 or AS3?

Comment: @SubashSelvaraj the games are externally hosted, I didn't develop them, I just published them on a blog...

Comment: You should have the source files(.fla) to do the stuff you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a SharedObject to store data locally, on the client side:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/SharedObject.html

This is very easy to implement:

```
var user_data_so:SharedObject = SharedObject.getLocal("myUserData");
user_data_so.data.name = "User Name";
user_data_so.data.score = user_score;
```

SharedObjects also work with a NetConnection (see getRemote), although I haven't used this method.  Other than that, a server-side script in any language you're comfortable with can accept a POST (or GET) from the client:

```
var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest(user_data_url);
req.data = user_data_xml;
req.contentType = "text/xml";
req.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;

// either this (will ignore server response):
sendToURL(req); 

// or (handles status, error, completion): 
var url_loader  = new URLLoader();
url_loader.addEventListener("complete",completion_handler);
url_loader.addEventListener("ioError",error_handler);
url_loader.addEventListener("securityError",error_handler);
url_loader.addEventListener("httpResponseStatus",status_handler);
url_loader.addEventListener("httpStatus",status_handler);
url_loader.load(req);
```

Comment: Thanks.. I guess the example code above is Action Script, but I dont know how to use that :| I grow up learning Javascript, then PHP, then Python, then Node.js... I never learn AS :( So I dont how to implement your code. Thanks anyway @dhc

Comment: this is tagged as Flash, so I assumed it was a game implemented in Flash?

Comment: Nope, is a website where my little brother publish games, I'm giving the website some functionalities. It's from blogger.

Comment: I doubt you'll be able to get much useful information from the games without some client-side programming, unless the functionality is already built in.

Comment: Sorry I didn't specified that before. I want to do this "client-side programming", I probably have to use some AS, but.. How do I do that and especially What I have to do?

Comment: Actionscript is much like Javascript, so if you have a good background in Javascript you have a leg up.  Start with some good tutorials and take it from there.

Comment: So... It will work even if the games weren't developed by me? Or DO I have to have access to the source files (.fla) like @ SubashSelvaraj said?

Comment: Yes, you'd need access to the source files.